# Javascript animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

On my webpage I have a members button which animates a dropdown when toggled. The only problem is that it animates every time I load a page without clicking the button to cause the action. I would like it to only open when the button is clicked and be hidden completely the rest of the time.

The javascript I am using is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#members').animate({
        marginTop: '-80px'
    }, 0);

    $('.mem').toggle( function() {
        $('#members').animate({
            marginTop: '0'
        }, 500);
    },
    function() {
        $('#members').animate({
        marginTop: '-80px'
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

As you can see it first animates the div to be -80px. I want it to be -80px without having to animate it every time I load up any page.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, i can see it :) then don't animate it and change the animate keyword with css.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me, it still shows up every time I load a page. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To #members css class, just add that:

```
display:none;
```

I also updated the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#members').css({
        marginTop: '-80px'
    });
    $('.mem').toggle(function(){
        $('#members').css({
            display: 'block'
        });
        $('#members').animate({
            marginTop: '0'
        }, 500);
    },
    function(){
        $('#members').animate({
            marginTop: '-80px'
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't I'm afraid. The top section seems to be animating it so it will just animate the display: none I imagine.

Comment: still no luck! If it helps, here's the website: http://ll13drjj.leedsnewmedia.net/redesign/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the animate function to a button click. Since you haven't posted the HTML, you'll need to replace "buttonSelector" with the actual selector you want to use.

**For example**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(buttonSelector).click(function () {
        $('#members').animate({
            marginTop: '-80px'
        }, 0);
        $('.mem').toggle(function () {
            $('#members').animate({
                marginTop: '0'
            }, 500);
        }, function () {
            $('#members').animate({
                marginTop: '-80px'
            }, 500);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post the HTML. The button which triggers it is the .mem div.